# C# decode public key from pem format

Tags: c#, python, cryptography, rsa, pem

I wrote this code for decoding my public key but this can not decode that. My converted base64 public key is `Convert.FromBase64String("MCgCIQCWeC4U3lLF7JCJePjZpK9rd1TOsqbT+/8TT++WL1kuFwIDAQAB)"` and this is input of `DecodeX509PublicKey` function. The key is generated by python rsa module.

python code:

```
pub, prv = rsa.newkeys(256)
pub_pem = pub.save_pkcs1(format='PEM')
pub_pem.replace('-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n', '').replace('-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n', '')
```

C# code:

```
//------- Parses binary asn.1 X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo; returns RSACryptoServiceProvider ---
    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeX509PublicKey(byte[] x509key)
    {
        // encoded OID sequence for  PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"
        byte[] SeqOID = {0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00} ;
        byte[] seq = new byte[15];
        // ---------  Set up stream to read the asn.1 encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo blob  ------
        MemoryStream  mem = new MemoryStream(x509key) ;
        BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(mem) ;    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
        byte bt = 0;
        ushort twobytes = 0;

        try{

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if(twobytes == 0x8130)  //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
            else if(twobytes == 0x8230)
                binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
            else
                return null;
            seq = binr.ReadBytes(15);       //read the Sequence OID
            if(!CompareBytearrays(seq, SeqOID)) //make sure Sequence for OID is correct
                return null;

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if(twobytes == 0x8103)  //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Bit String is 03 81)
                binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
            else if(twobytes == 0x8203)
                binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
            else
                return null;

            bt = binr.ReadByte();
            if(bt != 0x00)      //expect null byte next
                return null;

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if(twobytes == 0x8130)  //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
            else if(twobytes == 0x8230)
                binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
            else
                return null;

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            byte lowbyte = 0x00;
            byte highbyte = 0x00;

            if(twobytes == 0x8102)  //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Integer is 02 81)
                lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();  // read next bytes which is bytes in modulus
            else if(twobytes == 0x8202) {
                highbyte = binr.ReadByte(); //advance 2 bytes
                lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
            }
            else
                return null;
            byte[] modint = {lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00} ;   //reverse byte order since asn.1 key uses big endian order
            int modsize = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0) ;

            byte firstbyte = binr.ReadByte();
            binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);

            if(firstbyte == 0x00)   {   //if first byte (highest order) of modulus is zero, don't include it
                binr.ReadByte();    //skip this null byte
                modsize -=1  ;  //reduce modulus buffer size by 1
            }

            byte[] modulus = binr.ReadBytes(modsize);   //read the modulus bytes

            if(binr.ReadByte() != 0x02)         //expect an Integer for the exponent data
                return null;
            int expbytes = (int) binr.ReadByte() ;      // should only need one byte for actual exponent data (for all useful values)
            byte[] exponent = binr.ReadBytes(expbytes);


            //Console.WriteLine("\nExponent", exponent);
            //Console.WriteLine("\nModulus", modulus) ;    

            // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
            RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
            return RSA;
        }
        catch(Exception){
            return null; 
        }

        finally { binr.Close(); }

    }
```

Why `DecodeX509PublicKey` function can not decode the public key?

Comment: What does "can not decode the public key" mean? What *does* happen?

Comment: The function returns null in its first `if else` statement.

Comment: PEM processing is recommended to go through a library such as Bouncy Castle.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a test public key with a bit size of 256 bits. That's way too small to be useful. Now the issue is that BER encodes the length in:

- 1 byte if the size of the value field is < 128 bytes (just the length)
- 2 bytes if the size of the value field is < 256 bytes (`81 XX`, where `XX` is just the length as an unsigned number, represented here in hex)
- 3 bytes if the size of the value field is < 65536 bytes (`82 XX YY`, where `XX YY` is the length as an unsigned, big endian encoded number, represented again in hex)

Of course if the value is very small then the first byte of the length does not start with `81` or `82`. Note that e.g. `84 00 00 XX YY` also has a valid representation sometimes.

Three ways of handling this:

1. implement the one byte length for the modulus (quick fix)
2. only test RSA keys of 1024 bit or higher (always a good idea)
3. use a BER decoder or even a full fledged ASN.1 library (also always a good idea)

Personally I would combine 2. and 3. .

Comment: I tested the second way but not worked. @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: Could be the sign or endian problem with the modulus and exponent. Usually I don't answer "not worked" error descriptions.